# How display www/logo.png in my shinyApp when I run it from terminal?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is what I have written:

```
column(3, tags$img(src = "logo.png", width="310px"))
```

When I run my code in RStudio, my logo is displayed correctly.

However, when I run it from my terminal using `Rscript app.R` it won't show.

Instead, I get the question mark in a blue square.

Here is my folder architecture:

```
folder/
    - app.R
    - www/
        - logo.png
```

Here is the last line of my app.R:

```
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(port = 8080, launch.browser = TRUE))
```

Am I missing something in life?

Comment: Try with `column(3, img(src = "logo.png", width="310px"))`

Comment: It finally worked building my architecture in a different way with global.R, ui.R and server.R